# Function Harmonic inside the unit circle |z|=1

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that the function $$U(r,\theta)=2\pi\  \arctan\left(\frac{2r\sin\theta}{1-r^2}\right)$$  where $0 < r < 1$ and $0 < \theta < 2\pi$ is harmonic inside the circle $|z|=1.$

This appears under the section "Possion's integral formula for a circle ", but I cannot see how to apply it here , also I have tried direct differentiation , but it gets extremely messy.....

Comment: It is actually 2 divided by pi!!